# oneDrive always opens in the wrong Microsoft account, and the needed Microsoft account's oneDrive does not open at all

Tags: office-365, onedrive

I have Office365 and made the mistake of signing in to another Microsoft account that I mixed up with the one that I used before.

Being logged in with the right Microsoft account that also has Office 365, I cannot get to oneDrive,

[image]

the website does not load at all and hangs, showing the default *about:blank*.

If I click on a oneDrive URL of my history, I get to the wrong Microsoft account to open the wrong oneDrive, but it shows an empty oneDrive at least. If I switch in that moment to another oneDrive and choose the one of the right Microsoft account my_mail.com, the website stays blank, but at least, and not as before, the browser shows the URL https://onedrive.live.com/?gologin=1&login_hint=my_mail.com.

I guess this is not even a problem of the other active Microsoft account since I cannot open oneDrive in the right account anyway, but you never know.

How can I enter the needed account's oneDrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your browser in incognito mode and open the onedrive website. It will ask you to log in. It allows you to enter a chosen email. After login, agree to stay logged in.

If you then go to the normal mode again, you will be able to double-click whatever history item and get right to the right Onedrive again. It goes without saying that also opening the oneDrive website will open in the right account again.

Thus, just logging in and keeping the login in incognito mode "heals" the forced wrong account in normal mode.